# Always append empty row to end of useFormArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am attempting to build interface using react-hook-form where there are "detail" rows on the parent data (think invoice lines on an invoice). When entering the details, I'd like to keep an empty row at the bottom of the data grid. The `useFormArray` hook provides an `append` function that seems like what I'm looking for. The problem is that I'm encountering getting it called at the right time.

I've tried watching the last row in the fields array, but that doesn't get called consistently when the form gets `reset()` when new data is loaded from remote.

This seems like something that shouldn't be as hard as I'm finding it to be.

```js
 const val = useWatch({
    control: form?.control,
    name: 'rows'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // This doesn't get called every time that the form is `reset`, sometimes gets called multiple times, etc.
    console.log(val);
    if (lastRowIsEmpty(val)) {
      append({}, { shouldFocus: false });
    }
  }, [val]);
```

Comment: See https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/10238#issuecomment-1499395447